# Help to write unit tests for batch job

Tags: unit-test, batch

I have a batch job that delete records from object that were created more than 13 month ago. Please help me to write unit test for this batch. Thanks

@IsTest
private class ABI_CXC_DeleteNVMData_Batch_Test {

```
public String query;

@TestSetup
static void setup()
{
    List<NVMContactWorld__InteractionEvent__c> testEvent = new List<NVMContactWorld__InteractionEvent__c>();
    testEvent.add(new NVMContactWorld__InteractionEvent__c(Name = 'Test Event'));
    insert testEvent;
    Datetime createDate = Datetime.now().addMonths(-13);
    Test.setCreatedDate(testEvent[0].Id, createDate);
}

@IsTest static testMethod void positiveTestMethod() {
    Test.startTest();
    ABI_CXC_DeleteNVMData_Batch records = new ABI_CXC_DeleteNVMData_Batch(query);
    Database.executeBatch(records);
    Test.stopTest();
    System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT Id FROM NVMContactWorld__InteractionEvent__c WHERE Name = 'Test Event']);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to writing Apex tests start by working through these [Apex Testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_testing) Trailhead units.

Asynchronous logic is run when you call `Test.stopTest()`. So to test the batch job, in the unit test method(s):

- Insert some data suitable for the batch job
- Call `Test.startTest`
- `Database.execute` your batch job
- Call `Test.stopTest`
- Assert that the results are as expected